# how do you deselect a word when clicking on it again?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How to deselect a word after making it clickable

What I want to do is add (I'm assuming) another JS so when they click on the word again, it'll appear back to normal without the black background?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting inline values for your code, just create a CSS class to handle this, then toggle as necessary.

```
    element.onclick = () =>   {
      element.classList.toggle('highlighted');
    }
```

And the class ...

```
.highlighted {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

A messier solution would be to add an if/else statement to your onclick function.

```
    element.onclick = () =>   {
      if (element.style.background == '#000') {
          element.style.background = '#fff';
      }
      else { 
          element.style.background = '#000';
      }
    }
```

The .split() function actually removes your spaces, so just make sure you fix that when appending everything back together as well.

```
inputValue.split(" ").forEach(word => { 
    const element = document.createElement("span");
    element.innerHTML = word + ' ';  
    ...
```

I've mocked up the class solution at [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/blecovich/pen/JjNqNxz).

Comment: Next time, you should post the HTML snippets you're working with as well. Just makes it easier to provide answers.   : )

Comment: THANK YOU soo much, it really was that simple. I assumed I had to do it all in JS and got very confused and yes, I will for  next time!:)